# Unknown radiator plumbing leak

Tags: engine

[image]With radiator cap stamped '18 psi', the (apparent) crox fitting of the threaded male plumbing(labeled 'drip' in the picture below) dripped red coolant after a rainwater flush, followed by 5 liters of red concentrated ethylene glycol.
The leak seems to have stopped, after my Jeep's '16 pound' cap was used on the radiator neck top. What is the steel pipe, shown ~80 millimeters down from the cap, and should I try to tighten it...or just be happy that it may have relieved unsafe pressure from the radiator itself?
Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

In many vehicles with automatic transmission, there is a portion of the radiator that is separate for cooling the transmission fluid. (1)

The metal pipe you are referring to is most likely a transmission cooler line.

On vehicles with extra towing capacity, these lines often run to another auxiliary cooler before returning to the transmission.

[image]

The leak appears to be between the radiator and the cooler fitting itself. If the leak persists, it may be cause to replace the radiator.

(1) [Karim Nice "How Car Cooling Systems Work" 22 November 2000.
HowStuffWorks.com.](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/cooling-system.htm)

Comment: Agreed.. if the metal line is leaking it's transmission fluid. A coolant/coolant cap refresh will not help fix it

Comment: Thanks for your advice, and red antifreeze was dripping from the male fitting, which apparently returns warm antifreeze from the transmission's water jacket. A similar steel pipe at the bottom of the radiator must send cooler antifreeze to the transmission's separate cooler(radiator).

Comment: I used a 32 mm wrench, 'end on', because that was easier access through the hoses, and the blue-crusted fitting tightened slightly. I didn't notice whether the 1/2 inch males threads to the left loosened slightly! Is that 32 mm brass fitting simply threaded into the plastic, with or without sealant?

Comment: [link](http://superfly.co.nz/radiator_plumbing.jpg